# How to change look of webpart?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a default webpart in SP where elements of list are shown.

The problem is that  elements are displayed vertical (one below other) and I need to make them horizontal (in one line). Where and how I can customize webpart template? Browsing webpart in SharePoint Designer doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

Add a DataForm Webpart to your page using SharePoint Designer. You can modify XSLT (or use Drag and Drop) to change the look and alignment of elements in the list.
This link should help you out: 
http://www.apps4rent.com/support/kb/article/sharepoint-data-form-web-part

Comment: Sahilloona, thanks for your advice, but I can't understand how I can modify XSLT even after visiting your link. In other CMS, e.g. Joomla, all is simple - you open template and edit it as you want. But it's real trouble for me with SharePoint.

Comment: Mmm - "Design" -> "Customize XSLT" - got it!